# Filtering and searching through 2 different arrays of objects with JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects, and I need to work out what is the best way to filter one of these arrays, with the objects of the other array?

First array is called `drinksType`

```
[
  {
    "id": "GROUP1",
    "type": "Water"
  },
  {
    "id": "GROUP2",
    "type": "Beer"
  },
  {
    "id": "GROUP3",
    "type": "Coke"
  },
  {
    "id": "GROUP4",
    "type": "Gin"
  }
]
```

And the second is called `drinksGroup` which is filtered against `drinksType`

```
[
  {
    "GROUP1": 1,
    "GROUP2": 0,
    "GROUP3": 0,
    "GROUP4": 0
  },
  {
    "GROUP1": 1,
    "GROUP2": 1,
    "GROUP3": 0,
    "GROUP4": 0
  },
  {
    "GROUP1": 0,
    "GROUP2": 0,
    "GROUP3": 1,
    "GROUP4": 0
  },
  {
    "GROUP1": 0,
    "GROUP2": 1,
    "GROUP3": 1,
    "GROUP4": 1
  }
]
```

And the desired result would be something like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "Water"
  },
  {
    "name": "Water Beer"
  },
  {
    "name": "Coke"
  },
  {
    "name": "Beer Coke Gin"
  }
]
```

So you can see if a key in `drinksGroup` has a value of 1 then I need to filter `drinksType` to get the type. In some cases there could be several keys that have a value of 1, and in that case I need to filter `drinksType` with all of them and join the types. Sigh!

So far my effort is this...

```
const dataKeys = Object.keys(drinksGroup);

drinks.name = [...dataKeys
            .filter((dataKey) => dataKey.match(/GROUP/))
            .filter((dataKey) => data[dataKey] === 1)
        ].join(' ');
```

This gives the result

```
  [
      {
        "name": "GROUP1"
      },
      {
        "name": "GROUP1 GROUP2"
      },
      {
        "name": "GROUP3"
      },
      {
        "name": "GROUP2 GROUP3 GROUP3"
      }
    ]
```

But I dont know what to do from there. Any ideas how I can do it? The project I am working on also has access to lodash if that would be easier? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var drinksType = [{"id":"GROUP1","type":"Water"},{"id":"GROUP2","type":"Beer"},{"id":"GROUP3","type":"Coke"},{"id":"GROUP4","type":"Gin"}];
var drinksGroup = [{"GROUP1":1,"GROUP2":0,"GROUP3":0,"GROUP4":0},{"GROUP1":1,"GROUP2":1,"GROUP3":0,"GROUP4":0},{"GROUP1":0,"GROUP2":0,"GROUP3":1,"GROUP4":0},{"GROUP1":0,"GROUP2":1,"GROUP3":1,"GROUP4":1}];

var drinksNames = drinksGroup.map((group) => {
    var name = '';
    for (var groupName in group) {
        if (group[groupName]) {
            name += drinksType.find((type) => type.id === groupName).type + ' ';
        }
    }
    return {name: name.slice(0, -1)};
});

console.log(drinksNames);
```

Would that work?

Be careful, if you're targeting IE `Array.prototype.find` isn't supported.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative possible solution.

```js
var arr = [{"id":"GROUP1","type":"Water"},{"id":"GROUP2","type":"Beer"},{"id":"GROUP3","type":"Coke"},{"id":"GROUP4","type":"Gin"}],
    arr2 = [{"GROUP1":1,"GROUP2":0,"GROUP3":0,"GROUP4":0},{"GROUP1":1,"GROUP2":1,"GROUP3":0,"GROUP4":0},{"GROUP1":0,"GROUP2":0,"GROUP3":1,"GROUP4":0},{"GROUP1":0,"GROUP2":1,"GROUP3":1,"GROUP4":1}],
    
    hash = arr2.map(v => Object.keys(v).filter(c => !!v[c])),
    res = hash.map(v => ({name: v.map(c => arr.find(b => b.id == c).type).join(', ')}));

    console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Map, filter:

```js
const drinksType = [{"id":"GROUP1","type":"Water"},{"id":"GROUP2","type":"Beer"},{"id":"GROUP3","type":"Coke"},{"id":"GROUP4","type":"Gin"}],
    drinksGroup = [{"GROUP1":1,"GROUP2":0,"GROUP3":0,"GROUP4":0},{"GROUP1":1,"GROUP2":1,"GROUP3":0,"GROUP4":0},{"GROUP1":0,"GROUP2":0,"GROUP3":1,"GROUP4":0},{"GROUP1":0,"GROUP2":1,"GROUP3":1,"GROUP4":1}];

const r = drinksGroup.map(e => Object.keys(e).filter(k => e[k] === 1))
  .map(a => Object.assign({}, 
    {name: a.map(g => drinksType.filter(({id}) => id === g).pop().type).join(' ')}
  ));
 
console.log(JSON.stringify(r, null, 2));
```

First we find groups with value 1, then filter types and create strings.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `drinksType` map of ids to types, then map each object in the `drinksGroup` using the `typeByGroupIdMap`:

```js
const drinkTypes = [{"id":"GROUP1","type":"Water"},{"id":"GROUP2","type":"Beer"},{"id":"GROUP3","type":"Coke"},{"id":"GROUP4","type":"Gin"}];

const drinkGroups = [{"GROUP1":1,"GROUP2":0,"GROUP3":0,"GROUP4":0},{"GROUP1":1,"GROUP2":1,"GROUP3":0,"GROUP4":0},{"GROUP1":0,"GROUP2":0,"GROUP3":1,"GROUP4":0},{"GROUP1":0,"GROUP2":1,"GROUP3":1,"GROUP4":1}];

const typeByGroupIdMap = drinkTypes.reduce((map, { id, type }) => map.set(id, type), new Map);

const result = drinkGroups.map((groups) => ({
  name: Object.keys(groups).reduce((arr, group) => {
    groups[group] && arr.push(typeByGroupIdMap.get(group));
    return arr;
  }, []).join(' ')
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use top down approach by filtering only properties who are truthy. It need an object with all groups and their associated types.

```js
var drinksType = [{ id: "GROUP1", type: "Water" }, { id: "GROUP2", type: "Beer" }, { id: "GROUP3", type: "Coke" }, { id: "GROUP4", type: "Gin" }],
    drinksGroup = [{ GROUP1: 1, GROUP2: 0, GROUP3: 0, GROUP4: 0 }, { GROUP1: 1, GROUP2: 1, GROUP3: 0, GROUP4: 0 }, { GROUP1: 0, GROUP2: 0, GROUP3: 1, GROUP4: 0 }, { GROUP1: 0, GROUP2: 1, GROUP3: 1, GROUP4: 1 }],
    groups = Object.assign(...drinksType.map(o => ({[o.id]: o.type }))),
    result = drinksGroup
        .map(a => Object
            .keys(a)
            .sort()
            .filter(k => a[k])
            .map(k => groups[k])
            .join(' ')
        );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```